# How do you limit the group by rows in an mysql query?

Tags: mysql

There are other questions on here that sound similar but are not. I have a query that returns a bunch of rows with group by and I want to apply a limit to the total group by rows, not the total rows used to create the groups.

```
ID    TYPE        COLOR        SIZE
----------------------------------------
1     Circle      Blue         Large
2     Circle      Red          Large
3     Square      Green        Large
4     Circle      Purple       Large
5     Circle      Blue         Small
6     Circle      Yellow       Medium
7     Circle      Black        Large
8     Oval        Blue         Large
9     Circle      Gray         Small
10    Triangle    Black        Large
11    Star        Green        Large
12    Triangle    Purple       Large

SELECT size, type FROM clothes WHERE size = 'large' GROUP BY type LIMIT 0, 5

TYPE       SIZE       ROWS
---------------------------    
Circle     Large      4
Square     Large      1
```

^^^^ 2 GROUP BY ROWS THAT HAVE ALREADY EXHAUSTED MY LIMIT

```
TYPE       SIZE       ROWS
---------------------------    
Circle     Large      4
Square     Large      1
Oval       Large      1
Triangle   Large      2
Star       Large      1
```

^^^^ HERE'S WHAT I WANT, LIMIT APPLIED TO THE GROUPS

There must be some subquery or something I can do here, but I'm not figuring it out.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Can you show some example  data from your table, and show exactly what result you want. Maybe you can also reduce the limit from 25 to 5 to make the example simpler.

Comment: I can't really post my real query and dataset as it's way too large, if this is answered cleanly it should apply.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me:

```
SELECT type, size, COUNT(*) AS rows
FROM clothes
WHERE size = 'large'
GROUP BY type
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Results in:

```
type      size   rows
------------------------
Circle    Large     4
Oval      Large     1
Square    Large     1
Star      Large     1
Triangle  Large     2
```

LIMIT should get applied after GROUP BY, so I don't understand the issue.

Comment: Yes, this does in fact work. My problem in my real query is that I was grouping by more than one thing which meant it was breaking it out in to separate rows.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, color, size, type FROM clothes WHERE size = 'large' GROUP BY type 
) AS baseview LIMIT 0, 25
```

Answer (score 0):

how about just counting how many there are?

```
select color, size, type, count(id) from clothes where size = 'large' group by size, type, color;
```

I'm new to sql programming but this should return the following, that way you use 1 line for each color/size/type combination and get a quantity count after it.

Red large shirt 4

Green large shirt 6

Green large pants 2

and so on...