# Join One to Many - Display First Row from Many Table per Foreign Key

Tags: mysql

I want to get the first 5 rows from gallery using the following query, but I want to only get the first match from _gallery_gallery_items per row.

So for example, I want to get dog gallery, cat gallery and subsequent gallery titles from gallery but I only want to get the first match from _gallery_gallery_items where _gallery_gallery_items.gallery_id = gallery.id.

So the results should look like:

```
id = 1
title = dog gallery
gallery_item_id = 70

id = 2
title = cat gallery
gallery_item_id = 102

id = 3
title = mouse gallery
gallery_item_id = 500
```

Subsequent gallery_item_ids should not appear for the dog gallery, eg. 72, 72

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT gallery.id, gallery.title, _gallery_gallery_items.gallery_item_id
FROM gallery LEFT JOIN
_gallery_gallery_items ON gallery.id = _gallery_gallery_items.gallery_id
```

And the tables:

**gallery**

```
id|title
1 |dog gallery
2 |cat gallery
3 |mouse gallery
```

**_gallery_gallery_items**

```
id|gallery_id|gallery_item_id
1|     1     |      70
2|     2     |      102
3|     1     |      71
4|     1     |      72
5|     3     |     500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve this using `MAX()` and `GROUP BY` aggreate functions

**For the last gallery_item_id**

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, MAX(b.gallery_item_id)
FROM gallery a
LEFT JOIN _gallery_gallery_items b 
ON a.id = b.gallery_id
GROUP BY b.gallery_id
```

**For the first gallery_item_id**

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, MIN(b.gallery_item_id)
FROM gallery a
LEFT JOIN _gallery_gallery_items b 
ON a.id = b.gallery_id
GROUP BY b.gallery_id, a.title
```

Comment: Except I think he probably wants the minimum b.gallery_item_id.

Comment: it should be "first match" not max gallery_item_id or min gallery_item_id because maybe in the example its just a coincidence that min  gallery_item_id is the first match

Comment: This is great. But one thing has been missed from the original question, how do I limit it to just 5 rows?

Comment: You want only the first 5 galleries? Just add a `LIMIT 0, 5` . See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058911/how-do-you-limit-the-group-by-rows-in-an-mysql-query

Comment: @beans as meewoK said it just needs to add `LIMIT 5` at the end of the query

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    g.id,
    g.title,
    (
        SELECT 
            gallery_item_id
        FROM
            _gallery_gallery_items gi
        WHERE 
            gi.gallery_id = g.id
        ORDER BY
            id
        LIMIT 1
    ) as gallery_item_id
FROM 
    gallery g
```

Comment: It's very inefficient to use Correlated Subqueries unfortunately.

Comment: yes i totally agree but in the question there's no mention of performance factor

Answer (score 0):

Like this it should work:

```
SELECT
  g.id,
  g.title,
  ggi.gallery_item_id
FROM gallery AS g
JOIN (
    SELECT 
      gallery_id, 
      MIN(gallery_item_id) 
    FROM _gallery_gallery_items 
    GROUP BY gallery_id
) AS ggi ON ggi.gallery_id = g.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have got table A and one to many relation table AB and the many table is B:

```
Select *
From A table_a
Left Join (select * from AB group by A_id) table_ab on table_ab.A_id = table_a.id
#... (rest is yours)
```

Thanks.